# Issue in running executable jar built by jenkins

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, executable-jar

I am having an executable jar ,when I try to run this jar ,it is giving me an error saying one of the bean is not available.But however, if i unzip this jar file 
 and replace any of the class file and zip it back, the application  starts without any issue.No matter which class is replaced, after zipping it back, the jar starts without any issue. Can anyone please tell what could be the issue here?

Please note that When the jar is created in local, it doesnt have any issue. But when I download the jar that had been uploaded to jenkins and try running it, It is giving this issue. As mentioned earlier if I replace any class file inside this non working jar and zip it back, even this jar starts working

Answer (score 1):

Your char in local environment cold be placed in such manner that the executable jar can "see" the necessary dependencies.
You need to package all necessary dependencies into your executable jar in order to make it run when you move your jar to other location. You can utilize maven-assembly-plugin to solve this, just add the following in your maven's pom.xml in your build setup:

```
<!-- BUILD SETUP -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        ....
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>path.to.your.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Hope it helps!